# es6 object spread operator in jsx of reactjs

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs

```
// modules/NavLink.js
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router'

export default React.createClass({
  render() {         
    //for example this.props={from: "home", to: "about"}
    return <Link {...this.props} activeClassName="active"/> // ???what does the statement compile to es5?
  }
})

// modules/App.js
import NavLink from './NavLink'

// ...

<li><NavLink to="/home">Home</NavLink></li>
```

The quesion is below:

`<Link {...this.props} activeClassName="active"/>`, what does the statement compile to es5, if this.props={to: "/home", children: "Home"}?

Comment: You can find out yourself: https://babeljs.io/repl/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Straight from the Babel homepage](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=react&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=%3CLink%20%7B...this.props%7D%20activeClassName%3D%22active%22%2F%3E):

```
React.createElement(Link, _extends({}, this.props, { activeClassName: "active" }));
```

I omitted the `_extends` polyfill, it basically resolves to `Object.assign` if it is available.

Comment: Is there an existing polyfill for object spread that you are aware of other than using the babel library?

Comment: Anything that serves as polyfill for `Object.assign`. Object spread is nothing but merging objects.

Comment: Perhaps worded previous comment inadequately. Meant using spread or rest element syntax within a plain object, without using babel.

Comment: Oh I see. You have to use a transpiler for converting *syntax* features. I guess Babel is the most popular one these days. I don't really know or use any others.

Comment: Am trying to avoid asking the Question if answer already exists at SO. Was incorrect at a comment at an Answer where was not aware that the babel feature was enabled at stacksnippets. Downloaded babel to try locally. Though, at that time, was only really interested in the spread and rest syntax functionality. Can only certain portions of babel by extracted and utilized? Is there a difference between the spread and rest element syntaxes within plain object? Are you aware of an existing Question/Answer which clarifies? Or, am incorrect, again, here; in that there is only object rest syntax?

Comment: Both object rest (`var {foo, ...bar} = object;`) and spread (`{foo: 42, ...obj}`) are part of the same proposal: https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread . *" Can only certain portions of babel by extracted and utilized?"* Yes, by default Babel does nothing. You have to enable the features you want to use. See https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/ .

Answer (score 1):

```
<Link to="/home" children="Home" activeClassName="active"/>
```